# D3 Sankey diagram with dynamic height\width

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I am trying to implement this Sankey diagram
http://bl.ocks.org/Neilos/584b9a5d44d5fe00f779

For large volumes of data chart goes out of the UI view.

I am looking for an implementation like this
http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033

A chart that dynamically adjust the height width properties.

I am new to D3, dont know how to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When the d3.js sankey is built, it is based on the initial width and height that you supply.  If you have many nodes/bands you will also need to adjust the nodeWidth and nodePadding to space the bands.  Typically you would setup an input box for height and width, allowing the user to enter the desired chart size (which you could default to screen.width/height) and then reload the sankey so that the diagram can be reinitialized to fit the new dimensions.  The flow example you linked to still requires a manual position of the elements...ie you need to click and scroll.  In short there is no automated way to resize the diagram to fit an unknown number of data elements.  Hope that helps.